# Django - get Month and Year from (Datepicker filter data)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

This is forms.py

```
class dateFilter(forms.Form):
date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%M-%D'],label='',required=False,
                          widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
                                                "placeholder": " Select a date",
                                                "class": "dateClass",
                                                "id": "datepicker",
                                                "name": "dateFilter"}))
```

This is my views.py

```
def bsoCharts(request):
#-----------Filter Section------------------------------------------

dateFilter = forms.dateFilter()
FilteredDate = request.POST.get('date')


return render(request, 'BSO/BSO_dashboard2.html', 'dateFilter':dateFilter )
```

This is my template where I render the form:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <form action="{% url 'BSO:BSO_Dashboard' %}"  method="post" autocomplete="off">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{dateFilter}}
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my JQuery for the datepicker:

```
<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
          }
});
```

This is the photo image of the datepicker, and the value after selecting a date:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9iTo.png)

After getting the results back in my views.py using this get method:

```
   FilteredDate = request.POST.get('date')
```

i'd like to grab only the month and the year using the below method so I can use it as a filter(contains) to another queryset:

```
   FilteredDate.month
```

However, it's giving me this error:

Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.POST` is the raw values dictionary that gets submitted. So the fields are almost always strings (or floats/integers). Never the python values they represent.

When working with Django forms, which you're doing, you should always call `form.is_valid()` to clean the form and then grab the values from `form.cleaned_data`:

```
form = forms.dateFilter(request.POST)  # create the form with the data submitted
if form.is_valid():  # check the form is valid (which populates cleaned_data at the same time)
    filtered_date = form.cleaned_data.get('date')  # this is a python date
    if filtered_date:  # since date is optional, check it was passed
        month = filtered_date.month
```

Comment: Followed your code without the 2nd if statement and it works! Thank you!

Comment: you declared the `date` field in the form as not required, so your form is valid if there's no date. Try posting without selecting a date and you'll see why the second if statement is needed.

Comment: Now for some reason I can't use the month variable declared inside the if statement. it's giving me this error:     
(Exception Value: local variable 'month' referenced before assignment)

Comment: Well of course, if you declare a variable inside an `if` you shouldn’t use it outside of it since it’s not guaranteed to exist. Either you need to move your code inside the `if` or figure an alternative default value to assign to it in `else`. Or reconsider your business logic (is `date` really optional?)

Comment: is it possible if I append the filtered_date.month to an empty variable outside the if statement? I need to use this on my filter queryset.

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you’re trying to do. This is just very basic python, don’t call an attribute (`month`) on a variable that could be `None`. Use `if .. else` to deal with the various cases.